# $string.IndexOf('.') inside powershell function returns method invocation failed

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```
Function doSomething($param1 $param2 $file)
{
...doing stuff
$pos = $file.IndexOf('.')
}

doSomething -param1 'stuff' -param2 'more stuff' -file 'C:\test.txt'
```

Returns error: Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'IndexOf'.

But calling it outside a function or from the command line works with out issue.

Is this a limitation of powershell or is there some trick to calling string functions inside powershell functions?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) is a method of type `string`.  I suspect that somewhere in `...doing stuff`, you're operating on `$file` in such a way that it becomes treated as a [System.IO.FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx).

I suspect this in part because I've tried to replicate it in my environment and got it to work:

```
function doSomething ($file) 
{ 
    # This gets the index of . in 'C:\test.txt', which should be at position 7.
    $pos = $file.IndexOf('.')
    $pos
    $file.GetType() 
}
doSomething -file 'C:\test.txt'
7

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Are you operating on `$file` at all, or using it to modify other files? If you are and don't mind the object being a `[System.IO.FileInfo]`, you can use `$file.fullname` to get your path string back.  This assumes that you haven't modified it in such a way that it has become a collection of FileInfo objects.

Comment: You were correct I was creating file a System.IO.FileInfo object. I was generating $file with get-childitem for a folder path. It doesnt need to stay as a System.IO.FileInfo object for what I need so I just converted it to a string $file.tostring() and I am able to use indexOf. Thanks for the help!!